# TableView and CollectionView in one ViewContoroller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` in one `ViewController`.

[image]

If `CollectionView` is below the `TableView` in a hierarchy, the scrolling and clicking work only for `CollectionView` but for `TableView` all interactions are not working at all and vice verse...

On the screen, there is only one visible element `TableView` or `CollectionView`, and it's controlled by `isHidden = true/false`

What is wrong have I missed? How to have both `TableView` and `CollectionView` scrollable/clickable and manage that which is visible on the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to manage `isHidden` for containers like

```
container1.isHidden = true / false
container2.isHidden = true / false
```

`tableView`/`collectionView` are just subviews of their containers so hiding/unhiding them doesn't make the ability to interact with back-most one